# Error in a piece of code written by expl3 (correct usage of { O{} m })

Tags: pdftex, errors, expl3, xparse

Consider the following piece of code that I copied and modified it from `cas-common.sty`:

```
\tl_new:N \g_stm_mydate_day_tl
\tl_new:N \g_stm_mydate_year_tl

\cs_new:Npn \date_parse:n #1 { \date_parse_aux:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \date_parse_aux:w #1 / #2 / #3 \q_stop
{ <do something with the date> } %<------ What does this? It is a warning or it is ready to write a command instead of text?

\NewDocumentCommand \storemydate { O{} m }
{
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { day }
    { \tl_if_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_mydate_day_tl { #2 } }
    { \tl_if_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_mydate_year_tl { #2 } }
}
```

First of all, what do the third and forth codes do?

Second, I know that last code is a command and I can use it as `\storemydate[optional]{argument}` and it seems that the first returns for true comparison and second for false result. But when I use `\storemydate[day]{02 September}` it return `Undefined control sequence. \storemydate[day]{02 Sep}` error. (`Pdflatex` TexLive 2021)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_stm_mydate_day_tl
\tl_new:N \g_stm_mydate_year_tl

\cs_new:Npn \date_parse:n #1 { \date_parse_aux:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \date_parse_aux:w #1 / #2 / #3 \q_stop
{ <do something with the date> } %<------ What does this? It is a warning or it is ready to write a command instead of text?

\NewDocumentCommand \storemydate { O{} m }
{
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { day }
    { \tl_if_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_mydate_day_tl { #2 } }
    { \tl_if_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_mydate_year_tl { #2 } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \storemydate[day]{02 Sep}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’d not take `cas-common` as a model for `expl3` programming.

Comment: @egreg But for temporary usage it is fine. isn't? I usually don't like learning from 0 to 100. I like to start from middle of something.

Comment: Really: `cas-common.sty` is full of “don't-do-it-in-expl3” parts. You learn nothing from it.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for recommendation. Do you know a complete and short Journal/Thesis/Book template based on expl3 for learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the error message, which is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \tl_if_gput_right:Nn 
                                \g_stm_mydate_day_tl {02 Sep}
l.24     \storemydate[day]{02 Sep}
                                  
?
```

showing `\tl_if_gput_right:Nn` is undefined, possibly a typo for `\tl_gput_right:Nn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_stm_mydate_day_tl
\tl_new:N \g_stm_mydate_year_tl

\cs_new:Npn \date_parse:n #1 { \date_parse_aux:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \date_parse_aux:w #1 / #2 / #3 \q_stop
{ <do something with the date> } %<------ What does this? It is a warning or it is ready to write a command instead of text?

\NewDocumentCommand \storemydate { O{} m }
{
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { day }
    { \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_mydate_day_tl { #2 } }
    { \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_mydate_year_tl { #2 } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \storemydate[day]{02 Sep}
    
\end{document}
```

runs without error and stores the main argument in `\g_stm_mydate_year_tl` unless `[day]` is used.

`\usepackage{xparse}`  is only needed in older releases, to define `\NewDocumentCommand`

```
\cs_new:Npn \date_parse:n #1 { \date_parse_aux:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \date_parse_aux:w #1 / #2 / #3 \q_stop
{ <do something with the date> } %<------ What does this? It is a warning or it is ready to write a command instead of text?
```

is a sketch unused here to split up a yyyy/mm/dd format date so that the unwritten code in `<do something with the date>` can use `#1` as year, `#2` as month and `#3` as day

Comment: But my TeX error is just `Undefined control sequence. \storemydate[day]{02 Sep}`. Why it is different in your system?

Comment: @C.F.G no, that is not the format of a tex error message, look in your log file. If you are using texstudio you could try reporting (again) that it completely destroys the meaning of the error messages in its "summary"

Comment: reported since at least 2016 https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/